# google sheets - reference last column in range

Tags: google-sheets

I have and **COUNTIF** condition, where I count "Y".
If I add more columns, I need to update range in formula of N2 last column (AX123...).

How to reference last column in this formula so if I add more columns, it range from C2 to {last_column}2 ?

Example: I will add one more column to end, formula should look like =COUNTIF(C2:M2, "Y")

[image: sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*you can directly just use `C2:2` in place of `C2:N2`*